# Decrease a column of values by a given percentage in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with a column of values (in dollars) that needs to be decreased by a percentage. 
For example:

`df=data.frame(matrix(0,nrows=4,ncol=2))
colnames(df) <- c("ID", "Cost")
df$Cost <- c(2500, 1600, 1200, 6000)
df$ID <- seq(1:4)`

How would I decrease the "cost" column by 5%?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Answered, but I'm afraid the question is not in scope in this site and it could at best be migrated to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You just need:

```
df$Cost <- df$Cost * 0.95
```

Answer (score 0):

In R the columns of dataframes must be the same data type. Meaning, if you run `as.numeric(df$Cost)` or `as.integer(df$Cost)` one of those must be true to perform arithmetic operations over them. If they are, you can perform a single operation over an entire column, which is very efficient and easy to read. For your example, I would write the following:

```r
percent.decrease <- 5
df$Cost <- df$Cost * (100 - percent.decrease)/100
```

This way you can more easily change the percent decrease rather than doing the calculation elsewhere to arrive at 0.95 because mistakes happen.